# How to compare snowflake and csv tables using VS code(automation tool)?

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In case you know the solution but for some other automation tool, do answer.
I have already made a connection between VS code and snowflake using snowflake driver extension and SQL tool extension.

Comment: Any reason you don't simply load the CSV into Snowflake via the WebUI or SnowSQL CLI?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-web-ui.html

Comment: Otherwise, I would recommend you download the PowerBI desktop tool, where you can connect to a local CSV file and remote Snowflake account and perform a comparison within PBI directly.